# How to add custom extension for template in PHPixie?

Tags: php, phpixie

I want to write my own extension for PHPixie to use it in templates like this:

```
<div class="title"><?=$formatStyle($person->id, $format_id)?></div>
```

My extension class (see sample in [documentation](https://github.com/PHPixie/Template)) is:

```
\bundles\app\src\Template\Extensions\Extension\TYM.php
<?php

namespace Project\App\Template\Extensions\Extension;

class TYM implements \PHPixie\Template\Extensions\Extension
{
    public function name()
    {
        return 'tym';
    }

    public function aliases()
    {
        return array();
    }    

    public function methods()
    {
        return array(
            'formatStyle' => 'format'
        );
    }

    public function format($string, $formtat_id)
    {
        return 'asdf'; // TO DO
    }
}
```

Where should i place this file in my bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your class to `Project/Framework/Extensions.php` to `templateExtensions()` method.
In my project it is now looking like this:

```
/**
 * Extensions for the Template component
 * @return array
 */
public function templateExtensions()
{
    return array_merge(parent::templateExtensions(), array(
        //add your Template Extensions here
        new \Project\App\Template\Extensions\Extension\Base64()
    ));
}
```

I don't know full name for your class, so cannot provide full solution, only example :)

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works for my case: ```new \Project\App\Template\Extensions\Extension\TYM()```